# SQL Server 2005 Find the all the characters in between ##----## of column row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table **Template** with following columns:

**ID,   [Text]**

---

Suppose I have two records in a Template table,

1, 'His full name is ##Full_Name##,he was born on ##Date_of_Birth## in city of ##Place_of_Birth##'

2, 'I am ##First_Name##, I was born on ##Date_of_Birth##'

---

I want to find ##Full_Name##, ##Date_of_Birth## and ##Place_of_Birth## in a row.

In the other row there can be two match result which are ##First_Name## and ##Date_of_Birth## .

The output of the two records would be like that:

**1, Full_Name, Date_of_Birth, Place_of_Birth**

**2, First_Name, Date_of_Birth**

---

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What should the output look like please?

Comment: Good formatting is your friend.

Comment: How many columns would generally be in the output? It's not very clear from your description.

Comment: @Andriy-M Two columns, one would contain the ID, the other one would contain the extracted words like Full_Name, Date_of_Birth, Place_of_Birth. The three words would extract from the whole sentence and would be comma separated in a single column which would be second column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
DECLARE @Text NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Text ='His full name is ##Full_Name##,he was born on ##Date_of_Birth## in city of ##Place_of_Birth##'

DECLARE @Delimiter VARCHAR(1000)
SET @Delimiter = '##';

WITH 
    numbers(number)
      AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY o.object_id, o2.object_id ) Number
           FROM     sys.objects o
                    CROSS JOIN sys.objects o2
         ) ,
    counts ( began, number )
      AS ( SELECT   CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @TExt, 0)
                  , 1
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @TExt, began + 1)
                  , number + 1
           FROM     counts
           WHERE    CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @TExt, began + 1) > 0
         ) ,
    subs ( began, ends, number )
      AS ( SELECT   C.began + LEN(@delimiter)
                  , c2.began
                  , c.number
           FROM     counts C
                    INNER JOIN counts C2 ON c2.number = c.number + 1
           WHERE    C.number % 2 = 1
         )
SELECT  SUBSTRING(@TExt, began, ( ends - began )) Word
FROM    subs
```

Comment: the above code is not working. I am getting the following error; Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement CLR Regex function.

Here is an example: [Regular Expressions Make Pattern Matching And Data Extraction Easier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)

Comment: I want to do it in SQL Server directly.